# Django forms save override

Tags: django, django-forms

override save method in a form, I have an image that needs to be saved in a different database, but the rest of the fields should go to the default one, also I should store the image id in the default database

```
class TbUserRegisterForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = TbUser
        fields = ['username', 'image', 'email', 'sex', 'role', 'department', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: Different _database_? Do you perhaps mean different Model (table)? Please add the models to your question in that case. I ask because it is not possible to have relations across databases.

Comment: images are stored in the mongodb, the rest is mysql. I did not create this design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is How I usually overwrite save method in model form:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    # your logic or Save your object for example:
    obj = Model.objects.create(...)
    return obj
```

Or you can also do this:

```
def save(self, commit=True): 
    obj = super().save(commit=False)
    # do you logic here for example:
    obj.field = something
    
    if commit:
        # Saving your obj
        obj.save()
    return obj
```